# VS Code - Shortcut for toggling Git Open Changes and Git Open File

Tags: visual-studio-code

**How can I set shortcuts for it? Is it possible of using only one shortcut for toggling between two views Git Open Changes and Open file.**
Ideally, use only one shortcut for open changes and open file. When in the file it'll know to call open changes and vice versa, when in working tree version it'll call open file.

*I'm jumping between files and its Working Tree version by command palettes: **Git: Open Changes** and **Git: Open file***

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm either tapping command+p or using button next to "Close Window" button, it'd be great if there was a shortcut to toggle those two views.

Comment: @bruddha: yeah! I've found a way. Check my comment :D

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've found a way!

Open your **keybindings.json** ([How to open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48655811/1064858))

Add these config:

```
...
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+q",
    "command": "git.openFile",
    "when": "editorFocus && isInDiffEditor"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+q",
    "command": "git.openChange",
    "when": "editorFocus && !isInDiffEditor"
}
```

Now your vscode will work with **ctrl+shift+q** shortcut. Change to your shortcut.

Comment: anyway to close the other file? it opens both files, and focuses on the right file

Comment: I was also able to add these keyboard shortcuts by opening the Keyboard Shortcuts Menu (Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts), finding the relevant commands above, and changing the "when clause" by right-clicking on the relevant row and clicking "Change When Expression" to match the clauses above.

Comment: All I get is "git.OpenChange" is undefined.

Comment: @azizj1 git.openChange not git.OpenChange

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. It still does not work. Is there a certain extension I need installed to have that command available?

Comment: That link to "Open your keybindings.json" goes to another answer to this question which tells you how to open the Keyboard Shortcuts UI, not the `keybindings.json` file.

Comment: What is missing is that after opening the Keyboard Shortcuts UI, you need to click the icon at the top-right (in the file tab bar) which when you hover over it, says "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"

Comment: For those who are not working: The order matters, `openFile` should precede `openChange`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a shortcut for any command.

**File** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard Shortcuts**
or 
(Mac) **Code** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard Shortcuts**

Type the command you want to set a shortcut for to quickly bring it to the top and click the "+" button at the far left of the column and set the shortcut.