# How to close the git diff panel in vscode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is it possible, preferably using a shortcut, to close a git diff window in vscode. I know you can close the sidebar by pressing the ctrl/cmd + B. What about the file git diff window. That shows working file on right and original file on the left.

The reason is that I may have bunch of files and then I go to see what have I changed and see one file. I see something I want to fixed in it and then start editing it but there is left window showing git diffs which I just want to close. But pressing x on file name closes everything both the current version of file and last committed version.

I guess another way to ask this question would be how to go from git diff window to file directly.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a right click with the mouse on the file that you want to modify and click in the "*Open File*" option.

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: I used this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44737285/vs-code-shortcut-for-toggling-git-open-changes-and-git-open-file, and set my keys to cmd+shift+i for both going in and out of git changes/diff view

Answer (score 9):

**VSCode 1.65 (Feb. 2022)** - [Release Notes > Diff Editor Management](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_65#_diff-editor-management)

> There is a new command `Git: Close All Diff Editors` in the Command Palette that can be used to close all open diff editors.
>
> There is also a new setting, `git.closeDiffOnOperation` to automatically close diff editors when changes are stashed, committed, discarded, staged, or unstaged

**Related Issues**:

- [Add setting to automatically close Working Tree tabs when window is closed or when commit has been made](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141475#issuecomment-1035029035)
- [Git: stale editor inputs hanging around](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/18651)

Answer (score 2):

"I guess another way to ask this question would be how to go from git diff window to file directly."

There is a new command to do what you want coming in vscode v1.75:

```
workbench.action.compareEditor.openSide
```

It is currently in Insiders v1.75 and works well.

It is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> by default but you can change that.

So **whichever side of the diff has focus** when you trigger the command, the diff will be closed but that file will be opened in its own editor.

See [Allow to open either side of a diff editor as editor](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/7c721a065efcbc9a0b6b5ab5a9284d558857af4f).

Comment: Nice! I will definitively use that one.

Answer (score 0):

The Diff window shows when you are in the Source control section. If you want to just see the file (which it the right-hand side of your image) navigate to the folders section and click on your file.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Unfortunately, the author of this specific question is asking for a **directly**, so *without* reselecting it from the folder view.