# Keyboard shortcut to switch from source control "diff" mode back into normal editing?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I select a file from the source control panel (in my instance I'm using git), it then opens the side-by-side changes for that file.

I'm aware you can edit the file on the right hand side, but is there a quick way to close the open tab and open the original file itself? Preferably a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74779859/836330 it is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut I'm presenting as a solution is slightly long but will work for sure.

As soon as you open the file from the source control panel use the following shortcuts to copy the file's relative path

Windows/Linux `ctrl+k` Mac `cmd+k` immediately followed by `ctrl+shift+c` \ `cmd+shift+c`

This will copy the relative path of the file
you can then use the command `ctrl+f4` / `cmd+f4` to close the opened history view of the file

then open the command palette using `ctrl+shift+p` / `cmd+shift+p`  and remove the `>` character and paste the relative path of the file using `ctrl+v` / `cmd+v`

When you open the file in the diff view take care not to click the cursor within the editor as this will move to editor focus. When in editor focus the command to copy the relative path will not work. However this can be fixed by changing this in the keyboard shortcut settings.